# How do I access a private constructor in a separate class?

Tags: c++, friend, internal, forward-declaration

I'm writing a library in C++.  I have two classes in my library, `A` and `B`.  I want to hide the `A()` constructor from any code that references my library.  I also want class `B` to be able to call the `A()` constructor.

I come from a C# background and remember little of my C++.  In C#, I would simply declare the `A()` constructor as `internal`.  I've read that the closest way to do this in C++ is a combination of `friend` declarations and forward-declarations.  How do I do this?  Here are my three files below:

A.h:

```
#pragma once
class A
{
    private:
        A();
};
```

---

B.h

```
#pragma once
class A;
class B
{
    public:
        A createA();
};
```

---

B.cpp:

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

A B::createA()
{
    A result; //cannot access private member declare in class 'A'
    return result;
}
```

---

I've tried adding this to A.h:

```
public: friend A createA();
```

I've instead tried adding this to A.h with a corresponding forward declaration:

```
public: friend A B::createA();
```

I've instead tried adding and `extern class B;` to A.h and making B a class like this:

```
public: friend class B;
```

I'm at a loss.

I think this might be easier if I have the `B::createA()` function return a pointer to an `A` object rather than an `A` object directly, but that won't do in my case.  I am emulating a closed API and the API call returns an `A` object rather than a pointer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably just need to drop the "extern" from your third attempt to turn it into a proper forward-declaration. Try:

A.h:

```
#pragma once
class B;
class A
{
    friend class B;
private:
    A();
};
```

Comment: The forward declaration is likely what he was missing.

Comment: That was it.  Thanks!  Is it possible to make only the `createA()` function a friend, and not the whole class?

Comment: @user2023861:  Yes it is.  You basically would copy the entire function signature (scope included) and place `friend` in front of it.  For example:  `friend A B::CreateA();`

Comment: @ZacHowland That won't work as `B` is only forward declared. And you can't define `B` before `A` since than you already need `A` since you are returning it from `createA`.

Comment: I was just about to say that it didn't compile.  It's not a requirement that only the function is a friend.  I'll keep the class as a friend.  Thanks again!

Comment: @DanielFrey:  You have to switch a couple things around (and you cannot do it inline), but yes, it can be done.  See my edit below.

Comment: @ZacHowland D'uh! Of course. I was also thinking it should work but I wanted to be sure so I tried it out and made a stupid typo. Yes, you are right, it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Unless absolutely necessary, you should have `A` construct itself (or have a factory that creates `A`).  If you really want `B` to do it:

```
class B; // foward declared

class A
{
private:
    A() {}
    friend class B;
};

class B
{
public:
    A CreateA()
    {
        A a;
        return a;
    }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    A a = b.CreateA();
    return 0;
}
```

**Note**:  You must forward declare `B` before declaring it a `friend` in `A`.

If you want just the function as a friend:

```
class A;

class B
{
public:
    A CreateA();
};

class A
{
private:
    A() {}
    friend class A B::CreateA();
};

A B::CreateA()
{
    A a;
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    B b;
    A a = b.CreateA();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `friend class A B::CreateA();` <- why did you have to add class key before `A` I wonder? I mean isn't that redundant?

Comment: @AngelusMortis You are stating that `B` is a friend of `A`, not that `A` is a friend class.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `external` keyword. Make it simple:

```
// In A.h

class B;  // Forward declaration

class A
{
    friend class B; // Make all the class B friend
    A();
};

// In B.h

class B
{
public:
    A createA() {}
};
```

[**Live Example**](http://ideone.com/iiBTNp).

Answer (score 0):

You can make B a friend of A:

```
class A
{
private:
   A();
   friend class B;
};
```